# iText7 Encryption PdfDocument

Tags: itext7

In upgrading iText7 I see there need to be a `EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128` Is that correct. I am also not seeing how to add the `writerProperties` to my `PdfDocument`

Old Version

```
pdfDocument.Writer.SetEncryption(true, null, null, PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY | PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING);
```

New Version

```
    WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
writerProperties.SetStandardEncryption(null, null, EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING | EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_COPY, EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
```

Comment: *"add the `writerProperties` to my `PdfDocument`"* - what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code of iText 7 for adding or encrypting pdf files with owner and user password.

```
public class EncryptPdf
{
    public static readonly String DEST = "results/sandbox/security/encrypt_pdf.pdf";
    public static readonly String SRC = "../../../resources/pdfs/hello.pdf";

    public static readonly String OWNER_PASSWORD = "World";
    public static readonly String USER_PASSWORD = "Hello";

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DEST);
        file.Directory.Create();

        new EncryptPdf().ManipulatePdf(DEST);
    }

    protected void ManipulatePdf(String dest)
    {
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(dest,
            new WriterProperties().SetStandardEncryption(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(USER_PASSWORD),
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(OWNER_PASSWORD),
                EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | EncryptionConstants.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA
            )));
        document.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I want to set EncryptionConstants to null

Comment: @Jefferson *"what if I want to set EncryptionConstants to null "* - `EncryptionConstants` is a non-instantiable class with a number of constants. What do you mean by setting such a class to null?

Comment: @Jefferson, How are you going to tell which encryption algorithm to be used along with the type of restrictions that you need to put in the pdf document? You need EncryptionConstants to define it.